# JQuery - Change CSS Background Image

Tags: css, image, background

So, I have this div in my HTML called 'G36C', I also have a CSS class called '#G36C', so the style is applied to the div, okay?

Now, I want to change the background image in the CSS style by using JS, but I cant seem to get it to work, below is the JS I'm using:

```
function weaponOrganiser(){

    alert("weapon test");
    var weaponOrg = "Vector";

    //G36C
    if(weaponOrg == "G36C"){
        //$("#G36C").css('background-image', 'url("' + images/weapons/G36C/G36C.png + '")');
        $('#G36C').css('background-image', 'url("/images/weapons/G36C/G36C.png")');
        alert("G36C applied");
    }
    else if(weaponOrg == "Vector"){
        //$("#G36C").css('background-image', 'url("' + images/weapons/Vector/Vector.png + '")');
        $('#G36C').css('background-image', 'url("/images/weapons/Vector/Vector.png")');
        alert("Vector applied");
    }
}
```

So, all I'm doing is checking if weaponOrg = G36C, then change the CSS background to G36C.png, else if weaponOrg = Vector, then change the background to vector.

Now, When I run the code, I only get the alert("weapon test") to show ... the rest of the alerts don't show, which suggests to me that the if statements aren't working ...?

Comment: any error in the error console?

Comment: do you have an element with id `#G36C` in your document?

Comment: Sorry, no errors .. also, my div isnt named 'weapon' ... its named 'G36C'

Comment: Waaaait! - I do get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined"

Comment: Are you getting the alert of weapon test?

Comment: Is there a div with the class of `#G36C` rather than the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is speculation because your code looks like it should work (assuming the images are where you say they are), but, are you sure `weaponOrganiser()` is fired after the `G36C` element is loaded in the DOM? Because that is the only way (in my limited tests) I could make it fail.

If you're using jQuery that would mean (a basic fix of) wrapping whatever calls `weaponOrganiser` in a `$(...)` call.

*If you're not using jQuery hopefuly this will help anyway, but I don't want to post an example for regular javascript, because while my jQuery is rusty, my real javascript has already sheared off and fallen by the wayside a few miles back. :)*